# Postgres: numrange() breaks under certain plans

Tags: postgresql

This query used to work well but now is causing trouble:

```
SELECT
    incoming.*,
    prescribed.*
FROM
    "CRM_DEAL_INCOMING_RANGES_M" incoming
LEFT JOIN 
    "CRM_DEAL_PRESCRIBED_RANGES_M" prescribed 
        -- join the two tables
        ON prescribed.klient = incoming.klient 
        AND prescribed.op = incoming.op 
        -- make sure ranges are correct - there really is data where range_to > range_from, we just want to skip it
        AND prescribed.range_from <= prescribed.range_to
        AND incoming.range_from <= incoming.range_to
        AND numrange(prescribed.range_from, prescribed.range_to) 
            && numrange(incoming.range_from, incoming.range_to)
WHERE incoming.klient = 4;
```

Please note that we are making sure that the range boundaries are in the right order.

The query ends with the following error: `ERROR:  range lower bound must be less than or equal to range upper bound`.

However, if I remove the `WHERE` condition, it works well!

The explain of the problem is [here](https://explain.depesz.com/s/JgPE), the explain of the working alternative (without `WHERE`) is [here](https://explain.depesz.com/s/Zrmr).

How can I filter out data on which `numrange()` would choke, when the planner can just move my conditions around?

Edit: for now I just moved the second part of the join condition out of the JOIN into the WHERE, but I feel like it's just dodging the planner for a short while.

```
SELECT
    incoming.*,
    prescribed.*
FROM
    "CRM_DEAL_INCOMING_RANGES_M" incoming
LEFT JOIN 
    "CRM_DEAL_PRESCRIBED_RANGES_M" prescribed 
        -- join the two tables
        ON prescribed.klient = incoming.klient 
        AND prescribed.op = incoming.op 
WHERE 
  incoming.klient = 4
  -- make sure ranges are correct - there really is data where range_to > range_from, we just want to skip it
  AND prescribed.range_from <= prescribed.range_to
  AND incoming.range_from <= incoming.range_to
  AND numrange(prescribed.range_from, prescribed.range_to) 
    && numrange(incoming.range_from, incoming.range_to);
```

(As a_horse_with_no_name correctly points out, this has different semantics from the original query - it does not matter in my specific case though)

Comment: I very much doubt that has anything to the actual execution plans. This is most definitely caused the data in your tables. You might want to run a select statement that simply displays the values for the upper and lower range in the select part. I'm pretty sure there is something in there that breaks your query. By adding the `where` clause you are simply filtering out the problematic data.

Comment: Assume the following scenario: integer column with some numbers (including 0). Want to show data where eg. 100 / <the number> is over 10 using something like `SELECT * FROM data WHERE num != 0 AND 100 / num > 10`. Yes it's contrived but you get my point - how do I make sure that only valid divisors reach the division, if the planner can rearrange my conditions?

Comment: Try a lateral join like this: http://dpaste.com/2KXA1MT

Comment: The lateral join solution works, just like the updated one I posted above. What is the reason why the lateral join solution is safe from the planner breaking it again?

Comment: Moving those conditions into the WHERE turns the outer join into an inner join. That's a different statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is *no* guarantee that join terms, `WHERE` clauses etc will be executed in any given order. If your query relies on that, it's buggy.

In this case the correct solution would be [a `CASE` expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html), which (mostly) forces ordering.

```
CASE
WHEN prescribed.range_from <= prescribed.range_to
     AND incoming.range_from <= incoming.range_to
     THEN numrange(prescribed.range_from, prescribed.range_to) 
          && numrange(incoming.range_from, incoming.range_to)
END;
```

Note that no `ELSE` clause is necessary here, since `CASE` produces `NULL` if no clauses match, and `NULL` is false for a `WHERE` clause.

This may also screw up index selection, but so will most other approaches like a subquery with `OFFSET 0` or (ab)using a CTE.

I'd argue that it's a misfeature for `numrange` to `ERROR` on inverted ranges, rather than doing something like flipping them or evaluating to null, precisely because it makes such queries hard to write.

Comment: Works like a charm + your explanation is going to the core of the problem. Thanks!